# How to solve org.json.JSONException: No value for responsetypes in Android?

Tags: android

I am developing and I want to show user register or not. Following is my code in this it shows correct response in Logcat but not show the message on app side(i.e registration success or registration failed message).I am trying to parse response but **logcat** shows message is "org.json.JSONException: No value for responsetypes"
How do I parse json data in this? Please suggest me!!
I have do changes as per suggested!
What else i have to do here?

// Following is response from server shows inside Logcat

```
{"signup":[
            {"sessionid":0,
            "responsetype":"failure",
            "message"‌​:"Username emailid already register."
            }
         ]
}

    // Following is my code

public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private EditText editTextfName;
    private EditText editTextlName, editTextDid, editTextBd;
    private EditText editTextPassword;
    private EditText editTextEmail;
    TextView txtBirthDate;

    private Button buttonRegister;
    Button buttonBdate;

    String selected_date="";
    int mYear, mMonth, mDay;
    Calendar myCalendar;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

        editTextfName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextfName);
        editTextlName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextlName);
        //  editTextDid = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextdid);
        editTextBd = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextbdate);
        //   txtBirthDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtBdate);
        editTextPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword);
        editTextEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextEmail);

        buttonRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonRegister);

        buttonRegister.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if(v.getId() == R.id.buttonRegister){

            // Get the values given in EditText fields
            String firstname = editTextfName.getText().toString();
            String lastname = null;
            String emailaddress = editTextEmail.getText().toString();
            String birthdate = null;
            String password = editTextPassword.getText().toString();
            String deviceid = null;

            System.out.println("Givennames is :" + firstname + " Given password is :" + password);

            // Pass those values to connectWithHttpGet() method
            connectWithHttpGet(firstname,lastname,emailaddress,birthdate,password,deviceid);
        }
    }

    private void connectWithHttpGet(String firstname, String lastname, String emailaddress, String birthdate, String password, String deviceid) {

// Connect with a server is a time consuming process.
//Therefore we use AsyncTask to handle it
// From the three generic types;
//First type relate with the argument send in execute()
//Second type relate with onProgressUpdate method which I haven't use in this code
//Third type relate with the return type of the doInBackground method, which also the input type of the onPostExecute method
        class HttpGetAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

            private Context context;

            private HttpGetAsyncTask(Context context){
                this.context=context;
            }


            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

                // As you can see, doInBackground has taken an Array of Strings as the argument
                //We need to specifically get the givenUsername and givenPassword

                String paramFname = params[0];
                String paramLname = params[1];
                String paramEmail = params[2];
                String paramBirthdate = params[3];
                String paramPassword = params[4];
                String paramDeviceid = params[5];
                System.out.println("userID" + paramFname + " password is :" + paramPassword);

                // Create an intermediate to connect with the Internet
                HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

                // Sending a GET request to the web page that we want
                // Because of we are sending a GET request, we have to pass the values through the URL
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://www.example.com/ypAndroid/api/signUp?firstname="+paramFname+"&lastname="+paramLname+"&emailid="+paramEmail+"&birthdate="+paramBirthdate+"&password="+paramPassword+"&deviceid="+null);

                try {
                    // execute(); executes a request using the default context.
                    // Then we assign the execution result to HttpResponse
                    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                    System.out.println("httpResponse// getEntity() ; obtains the message entity of this response");
                    // getContent() ; creates a new InputStream object of the entity.
                    // Now we need a readable source to read the byte stream that comes as the httpResponse
                    InputStream inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();

                    // We have a byte stream. Next step is to convert it to a Character stream
                    InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);

                    // Then we have to wraps the existing reader (InputStreamReader) and buffer the input
                    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);

                    // InputStreamReader contains a buffer of bytes read from the source stream and converts these into characters as needed.
                    //The buffer size is 8K
                    //Therefore we need a mechanism to append the separately coming chunks in to one String element
                    // We have to use a class that can handle modifiable sequence of characters for use in creating String
                    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

                    String bufferedStrChunk = null;

                    // There may be so many buffered chunks. We have to go through each and every chunk of characters
                    //and assign a each chunk to bufferedStrChunk String variable
                    //and append that value one by one to the stringBuilder
                    while((bufferedStrChunk = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
                        stringBuilder.append(bufferedStrChunk);
                    }

                    // Now we have the whole response as a String value.
                    //We return that value then the onPostExecute() can handle the content
                    System.out.println("Returninge of doInBackground :" + stringBuilder.toString());

                    // If the Username and Password match, it will return "working" as response
                    // If the Username or Password wrong, it will return "invalid" as response
                    return stringBuilder.toString();

                } catch (ClientProtocolException cpe) {
                    System.out.println("Exceptionrates caz of httpResponse :" + cpe);
                    cpe.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException ioe) {
                    System.out.println("Secondption generates caz of httpResponse :" + ioe);
                    ioe.printStackTrace();
                }

                return null;
            }

            // Argument comes for this method according to the return type of the doInBackground() and
            //it is the third generic type of the AsyncTask
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);

                System.out.println("Post result :" + result);
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
                    JSONArray login = jsonObject.getJSONArray("signup");

                    JSONObject jsonObject1 = login.getJSONObject(0);
                    String sessionid = jsonObject1.getString("sessionid");
                    String responsetype = jsonObject1.getString("responsetype");
                    String message = jsonObject1.getString("message");

                    Log.i("response",responsetype);

                  //  Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, responsetype, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                    if (TextUtils.equals(responsetype, "success")) {
                        Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "success !!" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else if (TextUtils.equals(responsetype, "failure")) {
                        Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "failed......!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }else  {
                        Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Invalid...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

               }
        }

        // Initialize the AsyncTask class
        HttpGetAsyncTask httpGetAsyncTask = new HttpGetAsyncTask(RegisterActivity.this);
// Parameter we pass in the execute() method is relate to the first generic type of the AsyncTask
// We are passing the connectWithHttpGet() method arguments to that
        httpGetAsyncTask.execute(firstname,lastname,emailaddress,birthdate,password,deviceid);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your json has a key called `responsetype`

whereas you are using `responsetypes` in your code

```
String responsetypes = jsonObject1.getString("responsetypes");
```

remove the "s" and it should work.

```
String responsetypes = jsonObject1.getString("responsetype");
```

Also update your HttpGetAsyncTask class with below parameter and constructor. So add below code in your HttpGetAsyncTask

```
private Context context;
//in constructor:
public HttpGetAsyncTask(Context context){
        this.context=context;
}
```

Then to initialize this calls use code as below -

```
HttpGetAsyncTask httpGetAsyncTask = new HttpGetAsyncTask(RegisterActivity.this);
```

instead of -

```
HttpGetAsyncTask httpGetAsyncTask = new HttpGetAsyncTask();
```

and to show toast use -

```
if (TextUtils.equals(responsetypes, "success")) {
    Toast.makeText(context, "HTTP GET is working...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
} else {
    Toast.makeText(context, "Invalid...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

This is because AsyncTask doesn't inherit context and hence UI elements cannot be called using `getApplicationContext()` in AsyncTask

Comment: here i get NullPointerException  JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);

Comment: i checked beacuse of context used in toast getting nullpointerexception error.......but stiill message not shown in app side

Comment: The above line doesn't use context so context cannot give an error in the line JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);

Comment: I dont understand why success or failed message not shown in app side i.e in toast? where logcat shows everything fine.Logcat shows correct response now.but app side dont show anything

Comment: Man check my answer and also check your code.  In the Toast.makeText the first parameter I have asked you to pass is context and you have written RegisterActivity.this how will it work?

Comment: Thank you it working now!!! But plz tell me how do i use sharedpreferences for login activity

Comment: Raise a different question for that as its not related to this question. Plus do some research and try out some code and if you are not able to do it then post a question with code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45544122/how-do-i-show-result-from-server-response-to-app-in-android  , In this login activty i want to do session with sharedpreferences how do i do?

Comment: Thats a different question. :) Plus there are lot of questions which can tell you how to save in SharedPreference

Comment: i'ii try first if not solve then i post a question again........Thanks alot for ur help :)

Comment: please help me for this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45605312/how-to-save-selected-radiogroup-values-to-http-server-with-url-using-android

Answer (score 0):

add an "s" to responsetype because in your json

```
{"signup":[
        {"sessionid":0,
        "responsetype":"failure",
        "message"‌​:"Username emailid already register."
        }
    ]
}
```